# How Do I Fix My Super Statements?

Tags: java, super, bluej

I put my super statements in the correct format, yet my only error is that it states that the  constructor object in class java.lang.object can't be applied to given types for this part of the code:

```
       super (openFile (filename));
```

Here is my current code now:

```
     import    java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
     import java.io.FileReader;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.OutputStream;
     import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
         import java.security.MessageDigest;
         import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
         import java.util.Vector;import java.io.PrintWriter;
         import java.io.BufferedWriter;
         import java.io.FileWriter;
         import java.io.InputStream;
         import java.io.InputStreamReader;
         import java.io.Reader;

       public class Buffin 
      {             
 private static boolean temp;
 /////////////////////////////////
 private boolean isKeyboard;


 /** Connect to the disk file with the given name.  If this
  *  cannot be done, connect to the keyboard instead. */

 public Buffin (String filename)
 {    super (openFile (filename));
      isKeyboard = temp;
 }    //======================


 private static Reader openFile (String filename)
 {    try
      {    temp = false;
           return new FileReader (filename);  // IOException here
      }catch (IOException e)
      {    temp = true;
           return new InputStreamReader (System.in);
      }
 }    //======================


 /** Read one line from the file and return it.  
  *  Return null if at the end of the file. */

 public String readLine()
 {    if (isKeyboard)
      {    System.out.print (" input> ");
           System.out.flush();  // flush the output buffer
      }
      try
      {    return super.readLine(); // in BufferedReader
      }catch (IOException e)
      {    System.out.println ("Cannot read from the file");
           return null;
      }
 }    //============
}[/code]
```

Comment: There is no `Object` constructor that accepts a `Reader`.

Comment: please follow the instruction of what compiler tells you! Since `Reader` have no constructor with `(Object)`

Answer (score 3):

Your class extends only the `Object` class, and it doesn't have a method or constructor called `openFile`. You would be fine if you remove the `super` call altogether.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, your class `Buffin` does not specify a super class; that means it has one super class, and that  is `java.lang.Object`. There is no constructor that takes a `Reader` in `java.lang.Object`.

You could store a `Reader` as a field in your `Buffin` class, or you might extend a super class that accepts one in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Super involves the constructor of the superclass, I see that the Class Buffin inherits no class. As @Sotirios Delimanolis said, no constructor accepting Reader in Object class.